# Filtering into a new CSV with headers in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, csv, header

I have a CSV with a basic list of people, their genders, and ages, and corresponding headers:

```
"First Name","Age","Gender"
"Adam",31,"Male"
"Bruce",36,"Male"
"Lawrence",34,"Male"
"James",32,"Male"
"Elyse",30,"Female"
"Matt",32,"Male"
```

I'd like to open this CSV in Ruby, go through line by line, and append all male members to a new CSV with the same headers, and save this CSV to a new file.

My code right now (which is not working)

```
require 'csv'

file = 'cast.csv'

new_cast = CSV.new(:headers => CSV.read(file, :headers => :true).headers)

CSV.foreach(file, :headers => :true, :header_converters => :symbol) do |row|
    if row[:gender] == 'Male'
        new_cast.add_row(row)
    end
end

File.open('new_cast.csv', 'w') do |f|
  f.write(new_cast)
end
```

The error message I am receiving:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/csv.rb:1692:in `<<': undefined method `<<' for {:headers=>["First Name", "Age", "Gender"]}:Hash (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  <
    from csv.rb:8:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/csv.rb:1748:in `each'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/csv.rb:1131:in `block in foreach'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/csv.rb:1282:in `open'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/csv.rb:1130:in `foreach'
    from csv.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

So, it seems like I'm doing something pretty wrong. What would be the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CSV#new` takes a "string or IO object" as its first argument, and an optional hash as its second, [per the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new).

So it looks like the error is actually caused by this line:

```
new_cast = CSV.new(:headers => CSV.read(file, :headers => :true).headers)
```

which should be

```
new_cast = CSV.new("", :headers => CSV.read(file, :headers => :true).headers)
```

Note the empty string.

But even with that, this won't write the new CSV. For that, I think you want to `write_headers` in your new CSV, and then `rewind` it before writing, exposing the underlying [IO object](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-i-rewind).

```
require 'csv'

file = 'cast.csv'

new_cast = CSV.new("", :headers => CSV.read(file, :headers => :true).headers, write_headers: true)

CSV.foreach(file, :headers => :true, :header_converters => :symbol) do |row|
  if row[:gender] == 'Male'
    new_cast.add_row(row)
  end
end

CSV.open('new_cast.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  new_cast.rewind
  new_cast.each {|row| csv << row}
end
```

Hope that helps!